Orthogonality of Whittaker functions
Is there a known orthogonality property of Whittaker functions $W_{\kappa,\mu}(iz)$ with respect to the first index as an integral over the argument? I am particularly interested in the case $\mu=0$ and imaginary argument because these relate to the paraboloidal wave functions. I.e. something of the form
$$ \int W_{\kappa_1,0}(iz) W_{\kappa_2,0}(iz) w(z) d z = \delta(\kappa_1-\kappa_2)$$
for an appropriate integral domain and weight $w(z)$? What are the best resources for this?

I posed this question on the Perplexity AI (https://www.perplexity.ai/): Are there any instances of orthogonality in the Whittaker functions? The answer was positive, you should check it out.

Thanks, I guess it would be hard to find if it exists then...
